# ¿Porque este bucle while no funciona?

Tags: python

> Tengo un problema, quise hacer un juego de Piedra papel o tijera en Python, tuve que usar varios if ya que en Python no hay switch, y bueno, use un bucle while para hacer que funcione:

```
import random
jugada = 0;
computador = 0;
puntosj = 0;
puntosc = 0;
ronda = 1;
while (puntosc < 3 or puntosj < 3):
  computador = random.randrange(3);
  print("Piedra:0, Papel:1,Tijera:2");
  jugada = input("Digite su jugada");
  if (jugada == 0 and computador ==    0):
    print("Empate en la ronda "+ronda);
  if (jugada == 0 and computador == 1):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosc += 1;
  if (jugada == 0 and computador == 2):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosj += 1;
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 0):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosj += 1;
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 1):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Empate en la ronda "+ronda);
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 2):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosc += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 0):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosc += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 1):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero "+ronda);
    puntosj += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 2):
    print("Computador jugo "+computador);
    print("Empate en la ronda numero "+ronda);
    ronda += 1;
if puntosc < puntosj:
  print("Ganaste :)")
if puntosj < puntosc:
  print("Perdiste :(")
```

> Quizás el error fue que use la librería incorrecta para usar random.randrange, o use mal el while o el if, estuve intentando arreglar el código, no creo que sea un error de sintaxis porque el programa no me daba error, pero no hace lo que yo quería que hiciera. Ojalá alguien me pueda ayudar come este problema

Comment: ¿En verdad está bien indentado el código? De no ser así, edita tu pregunta e indéntalo tal cual lo tienes realmente.

Comment: Que version de python es?, además identa tu codigo, en python la identacion es esencial

Comment: Ya he editado el código, por si acaso mi código estaba bien indetado, solo que lo puse mal en la pregunta, la versión de Python es 3.

Answer (score 2):

El código que tienes de momento no funciona bien porque estás comparando `STR` con `INT` en los `if`. Arreglando eso vas a tener otros problemas de concatenación de `str` con enteros y los valores generados al azar en los `print()`

---

Qué tal si en vez de generar tantos `if`, utilizas otra estructura de datos de la siguiente forma:

```
ppt = {id_piedra, [nombre, vence_a], id_papel : [nombre, vence_a], ...}
```

Los id son como tu los defines: `'0'` piedra, `'1'` papel `'2'` tijera

Si el `id_introducido` es igual al id generado al azar, entonces es empate
Si el valor `ppt[id_introducido][1]` es igual al valor generado al azar (computador), coincide con el elemento que vence, por lo tanto computador pierde.
Finalmente (`else`), si no coincide las dos opciones anteriores, es porque computador gana.

```
import random

puntosj = puntosc = empate = 0
ronda = 1;
ppt = {"0": ['piedra', '2'], '1':['papel', '0'], '2':['tijera', '1']}

print("Piedra:0, Papel:1,Tijera:2");
while True:
    jugada = input(f"[Ronda {ronda}] - Digite su jugada o [x] salir: ")
    if jugada.lower() == "x": # salir
        break
    if jugada not in ["0", "1", "2"]:
        print("Entrada no valida")
        continue
    # Empieza el juego
    computador = str(random.randrange(3))
    partida = f"Humano [{ppt[jugada][0]}] vs [{ppt[computador][0]}] CPU"
    if jugada == computador:
        print(f"{partida} -- EMPATE")
        empate += 1
    elif ppt[jugada][1] == computador:
        print(f"{partida} -- GANA HUMANO")
        puntosj += 1
    else:
        print(f"{partida} -- GANA CPU")
        puntosc += 1
    ronda += 1
    print()

print("\nFIN DEL JUEGO")
print(f"Humano {puntosj} | Computador {puntosc} | empates {empate}")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! La verdad no se mucho de Python. De verdad muchas gracias por ayudarme

Answer (score 0):

soy muy nuevo en esto, consegui que funcionara tu codigo modificandolo de esta manera:

```
import random
jugada = 0
computador = 0
puntosj = 0
puntosc = 0
ronda = 1
while ((puntosc < 3) or (puntosj <3)):
  computador = random.randrange(0,3)
  print ("ganadas computador: ",puntosc,"ganadas jugador: ",puntosj)
  print("Piedra:0, Papel:1,Tijera:2")
  jugada =int (input("Digite su jugada: "))
  print ("computador jugo: ", computador)
  print ("tu jugada: ", jugada,"\n")
  if (jugada == 0 and computador == 0):
    print("Empate en la ronda ",ronda)
  if (jugada == 0 and computador == 1):
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosc += 1
  if (jugada == 0 and computador == 2):
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosc += 1
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 0):
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosj += 1
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 1):
    print("Empate en la ronda ",ronda)
  if (jugada == 1 and computador == 2):
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosc += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 0):
    print("Perdiste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosc += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 1):
    print("Ganaste la ronda numero ",ronda)
    puntosj += 1;
  if (jugada == 2 and computador == 2):
    print("Empate en la ronda numero ",ronda)
  if puntosc ==3:
    break
  if puntosj ==3:
    break
  ronda+=1
  print ("==========================================")



        
if puntosc < puntosj:
    print("=============Ganaste :)===============")
else:
    print("=============Perdiste :(==============")
```

Lo que si, te aconsejo identar mejor tu codigo, como asi tambien leer un poco sobre la sintaxis de python, ya que habia muchisimos errores.lo que no se muy bien es como frenar el while cuando llega a 3, por lo que utilize dos if con break al final del while. Abrazo!

Comment: Te puedes ahorra mucho código, solo haciendo la comparación, ```jugada == computador``` eso significa que hay empate